# Can I enabled the 'Firebase Management API' from the command line?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to automate my google cloud project creation using gcloud and firebase cli.

When I try to create a firebase app using 'firebase apps:create' command, I get an error telling me I need to go to the google cloud console to enable the Firebase Management API for the the project. Not manually going to the google cloud console is EXACTLY what I am trying to avoid my writing this command line script.

Is there are way I can enable this API for a project from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable any Google API|service using Google's [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) CLI.

> **NOTE** This is distinct to the `firebase` CLI.

You should be able to:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]

gcloud services enable firebase.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Or, if you replace `{PROJECT}` with the value in the URL, you can browse the service management page and enable it if necessary:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/firebase.googleapis.com?project=${PROJECT}
```

There are several ways to determine the service (and URI) names.

You can:

1. `gcloud services list --available --project=${PROJECT}`
2. You can search using [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library)
3. You can search using [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer)